# Query Bounce more than 6 months old

Tags: marketing-cloud

Bounce info is present in _bounce dataview. The dataview only store last 6 months info. is it possible to query bounce info which is older than last 6 months like last 4 years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For data older than 6mths you want to use a [tracking data extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5) There is no limit of data you can access through this process (just 30 days at a time)

Comment: Thanks a lot EazyE. I am now using Tracking Extract. Initially has lots of problem with CSV form as the bounce info had spaces or comma in content as well. Now i moved it to xml and its going good. Thanks for your help